# Print generated list of 20 random numbers + print different list w/ same #s from first list w/o duplicate #s

Tags: java, for-loop, random, integer

I'm trying to make a program that generates 20 random integers between 1 and 20 and then prints the list of random numbers to the screen. After that, I want to print a different list to screen with the same numbers from the first list only skipping any number that has been already printed to the screen. Currently, my code generates 20 numbers from 1 to 20. I don't know how to print the s different list only without duplicate numbers. I appreciate everyone who helps me in advance!

```
public void randomNumbers(){
    System.out.println("Twenty random integers: ");
    for (int x = 0; x < 20; x++){
        int max = 20; //max value for range
        int min = 1; //min value for range
        Random rand = new Random();
        int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;//generates random # within range
        System.out.println(randomNum);
    }
System.out.println("Twenty random integers w/o duplicates: ");
}
```

Comment: Store the numbers in a `Set`.

Comment: Your description says that you want to print a list of numbers and then print the same list skipping ones already printed. Doesn't that mean that the second time you won't print anything? Or do you mean a different list?

Comment: @sprinter Sorry that I wasn't clear. I want to print the same list that is printed the first time only with out duplicate numbers. So two lists are printed to the screen. The first one has 20 random numbers. The second one has those same 20 numbers but only prints the numbers in the first list that aren't duplicated. So if my list of 20 random integers contains three 2s and two 14s, only one 14 and one 2 is printed to the second list.

Comment: @Jake ok that makes sense now. I've posted a way to do it with streams if you are interested.

Comment: @sprinter Yes, I am interested but to be honest this is the first time I've heard of java streams haha.

Comment: They are worth getting to know - I'll add an explanation to my answer.

Comment: @sprinter I know this is a lot to ask but could you also fix my code using an array or hashset (something I'm more familiar with) so I can continue my program before I do more research and practice with streams?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70033/discussion-between-speedo-and-sprinter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to solve this without streams then a simple mechanism is to add the numbers to a set as you print them:

```
Random rand = new Random();
Set<Integer> randSet = new TreeSet<>();
for (int x = 0; x < 20; x++){
    int randomNum = rand.nextInt(20) + 1;
    randSet.add(randomNum);
    System.out.println(randomNum);
}
for (Integer randomNum: randSet) {
    System.out.println(randomNum);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an interesting way to do it in one go with Java 8 streams:

```
Random rand = new Random();
IntStream.generate(rand::nextInt).limit(20).map(n -> n % 20 + 1)
    .peek(System.out::println)
    .collect(Collectors.toSet()).forEach(System.out::println);
```

If you are not used to streams then I'll translate it as follows:

- generate = give me an endless stream of random numbers
- limit = actually just give me the first 20
- map = convert the numbers to be between 1 and 20
- peek = print them out
- collect = put them in a set
- forEach = print out each of the items in the set